# bash and env: something: Permission denied

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, opensuse

I use openSuse Leap 42.1.

I had installed Skype long time ago. And it worked all that time. But recently it stopped start and when I run it from terminal I receive an error:

```
env: /usr/lib/skype/skype: Permission denied
```

I had googled this error but no luck.
Now I have installed new version of Android Studio and when it runs and download SDK and tools it said:

```
Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool
```

I went to terminal again and run `mksdcard` in it and get an error:

```
bash: ./mksdcard: Permission denied
```

My last installation of the previous version of the Android Studio was successful. I have tried install previous version now and get this error too.

I consider that these errors have one nature. But all my research don`t bring me success.

Could someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: The usual reason for this error is that the program is found, but you do not have execute permission. Run `ls -l /usr/lib/skype/skype ./mksdcard` and compare permissions with your log-in user (run `whoami`) and group. Incidentally, you have typed `mksdcard` without a path, and `bash` has found `./mksdcard`, which implies that `.` is in your PATH variable: this is never recommended.

Comment: I have sufficient permissions to execute this files. I run `skype` all time ago successful. And `mksdcard` is located in my own profile.

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-- 1 paola users 12K Mar 22  2014 mksdcard`

Comment: Try as I might, I cannot see a reason for this. You didn't give me the output from `ls -l /usr/lib/skype/skype`, but I doubt that this will tell me anything. All I can think is that you have run a script which has use `su` or `sudo` to change your user. Did you run `whoami`? Or try `:>tempfile; ls -l tempfile; rm tempfile` to make sure the file is created with your user and group names.

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 36499124 Jul 28 18:36 /usr/lib/skype/skype`

Comment: `-rw-r--r-- 1 paola users 0 Jul 30 10:45 tempfile`

Comment: I'm stumped! Maybe Android Studio runs in its own account, in which case `chmod a+x mksdcard` should solve this. I'm still concerned about `.` in your path (this can happen inadvertently if `PATH` has a leading or trailing `:`), as the wrong `mksdcard` may be found. Presumably  `skype` will run with `sudo`, but it's not recommended: not only does it give an internet program unrestricted access to your system, but it will probably run with a different profile (I am guessing, having never wanted to try it). Other than a re-installation of Android Studio or `skype`, I have no other suggestions.

Comment: @AFH: I had run `./mksdcard` in terminal from the folder where this file locates. And I tried to reinstall both of this apps with same result.

Comment: OK. You said you ran `mksdcard` and I wrongly assumed that this was what you typed. None of the rest of it makes sense. Sorry I haven't been able to help.